# Mention database.table.field in mysql query always fail

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy table from one database to another database but with not duplicate value from one database field.

```
INSERT INTO database.table1 (`fielda`, `fieldb`, `fieldc`) 
SELECT `fielda`, `fieldb`, `fieldc`
FROM database.table2 
WHERE database.table2.fielda 
  NOT IN database.table1.fielda
```

It always give me a query error message.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You have an error in last line

Comment: You need to escape `database` as it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO database.table1 (`fielda`, `fieldb`, `fieldc`) 
SELECT `fielda`, `fieldb`, `fieldc`
FROM database.table2 
WHERE database.table2.fielda 
NOT IN (select `fielda` from database.table1 )
```

Comment: Why do I need to select it again if I have mention it before?

Comment: @al_kasih_empatix:- You have to select the `fielda` column which are not present in table1 of your database. So you need to get the list of those `fielda` in your NOT IN clause.